# Is there a common convention to describe the encoding of a legacy text file?

Tags: text, character-sets

For the purpose of this question, a legacy textfile contains characters in the range 0x20 through 0x7e, with each line terminated by an OS-specific combination of 0x0d and/or 0x0a; it might be terminated by 0x1a. It does not contain markup or metadata enclosed by `<>`, a leading dot, or anything similar, and does not contain UTF-8 etc. encoded characters.

Is anybody aware of any historic attempt to add something to this that indicates what codepage is to be assumed if a byte in the range 0x7f through 0xff is encountered?

I'm obviously aware that email-style headers and things like JCL do it, but these are outside the file per se. What I'm interested in is any attempt to add something comparable with a Unicode BOM at the start of the file, or metadata appended after an explicit 0x1a EOF.

---

As further background: I've been researching the mess that surrounded the ALGOL-68 standardisation process, Wirth's withdrawal, and his design of Pascal. I believe that somebody on the committee acted in bad faith, that Wirth was in a position where he couldn't object openly, and that Pascal was his attempt to present the World with a working language before ALGOL got its act together: in practice ALGOL never really get its act together so his haste was unjustified.

As part of that, and as a longstanding Pascal user, I'm sketching out what I believe were Wirth's mistakes: many of which he later corrected (Modula-2, Oberon). However if I ever get to the position of working on a personal replacement, I'd need to sort out the character set (codepage) issue.

Wirth was on the cusp between 6-bit character sets, EBCDIC, and ASCII. Focusing on ASCII, there have been multiple codepages which contained the special ALGOL characters (assignment arrow etc.), which in many cases were also used by APL. Looking at the Free Pascal Compiler forum and mailing lists, codepages remain a major issue both from the POV of literals in the sourcecode and interpretation of textfiles as they are being read.

Taking that into account, if I ever get round to actually coding anything I'll need some way of handling both Unicode and arbitrary codepages, and I'm blowed if I'm going to make FPC's mistake and try to handle everything as UTF-8 internally.

I'm thinking along the lines of using 0x1a as a codepage marker, followed by CP and the codepage number or name, followed by another 0x1a. That would make sense in both ASCII and EBCDIC, and could easily be distinguished from data by looking at the overall length of the file.

Comment: Basically all schemes I am aware of either have this information as part of an already existing wrapper (which you rule out, "no metadata"), or outside of the file (e.g. as language settings on the system). And given the sheer amount of possible encodings (which goes beyond "codepages", e.g. think IBM EBCDIC), I'd be really surprised if any standards exist that doesn't require you to specify this as some kind of human-readable metadata.

Comment: That confirms my experience, but I'm interested if anybody has actually come across anything otherwise... including on e.g. an IBM DisplayWriter or a Redactron. I carefully avoided consideration of EBCDIC (or for that matter the multitudinous 6-bit codes) since (a) any metadata prefix/suffix would presumably have to itself adhere to some character encoding and (b) EOF markers etc. are likely to differ.

Comment: No tab characters (0x09)?

Comment: @dan04 No, and no backspaces, bells or whistles :-) I did think of that but decided to try to keep things simple, since once one has tabs one has to wonder about formfeeds, and once one has formfeeds one has to wonder about other positioning sequences (VT-100 vs VT-52) and so on.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: Well, in ASCII, backspace is 0x08.  Bells (or other audible alert, which would include whistles, as well as the more common beepers and buzzers) are 0x07 :-)

Comment: So you assume ASCII based encodings? So PETSCII text file can be left out? All computer systems seemed to be a bit special and not even fully ASCII compatible. Files were generally system and/or OS and/or program specific.

Comment: @Justme Frankly and bluntly: yes, I did.

Comment: The long first sentence boils down to “7 bit ASCII”.

Comment: I'm not clear on whether this is what you're asking but Firefox years ago had logic to detect the encoding of web pages and text files stochastically based on their bytes. It used to work extremely well but of course had problems with tiny files of say one word or one line in unusual encodings. I wouldn't be surprised if it still has this ability.

Comment: @RonJohn Yes, although I suppose I could have been explicit about that. In practical terms I think the rarity of floppies etc. connected to the PET- and I'd emphasise that I was an early user of those machines and am well aware of the HPIB expansion interface- reduces its relevance. If anybody wants to assign an honorary codepage to PETSCII don't let me stop you...

Comment: Don't forget the mess you got with 7 bit "ascii" in western europe. I think we had at least 10 national/language versions of it.

Comment: Regarding Wirth and Pascal: Wirth was probably well aware of the laguage/country specific versions of ascii. That was most probably the reason for allowing '(*' and '*)' instead of '{' and '}' and '(.' and  '.)' instead of '[' and ']'.

Comment: @UncleBod No, those were a restriction of the IBM 029 cardpunch. He started off on an IBM (704?) at Berkeley, moved on to a B5000 (six-bit character set) at Stanford followed by an IBM 360, and then various machines in Europe including CDC. However almost everybody in those days bought or rented (sometimes rebadging) the desk-sized IBM punches. More interesting is := as an alternative to a special assignment glyph, which goes back to Zuse and IAC.

Comment: @UncleBod: Include code segments in back-ticks, especially if they contain asterisks or underscores.  I think you meant `(*` and `*)`, which I entered as \`(\*\` and \`\*)\`.  As for `:=`, I like it better than `=` for assignment, though I like `==` for comparison.  I think `:=` would also fit the pattern established by compound assignment operators, but with the "how to combine" things using a symbol for the case where only the source value is used.

Comment: @supercat I agree with your comment about assignment, a single = could usefully be eliminated. Apart from that I'd prefer not to define e.g. backticks at the language level, but instead to be able to define them like operators (i.e. a simple character or string is in single quotes, but double quotes, backticks etc. could be defined as implying various types of interpolation etc.).

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd: Read your comment to which I replied.  As displayed on Stack Overflow, the asterisks were missing from the `(*` and `*)`, and the text `' and '` between them was italicized.  Using back ticks in your comment would have prevented Stack Overflow from interpreting the astserisks as a request to italicize text.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd _"No, those were a restriction of the IBM 029 cardpunch"_ Not really. The 029 (and EBCDIC) covered the whole ASCII character _range_ right from the start, including the optional variation and sharing that issue. As with ASCII it was all about how terminals and printers were configured - usually according to what the daily routine at a company required - like Umlauts in Germany. For European programmers it was essential that a language would not rely on those 12 redefinable characters (_"#$@[\]^`{|}~"_). Same as being case insensitive to support all upper case programming.

Comment: @Raffzahn I'm sorry, I disagree. If you read e.g. Schorre's original paper on Meta2- which he implemented on an IBM 1401- he uses specifically those words, and also a limited character set was my experience when using the 029 in the FORTRAN era. Also see e.g. https://www.curiousmarc.com/computing/ibm-029-keypunch noting the crucial lack of braces and (square) brackets in the illustrated character sets.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd you are aware that the 029 was introduced _way_ after the 1401? IIRC it came with (or short before) the /360. Yes, the 029 could be used with 6 bit machines, there was a special 48 character mode which also came in a variant for FORTRAN (on those CPUs). It is important to remember that code and glyph is arbitrary, no matter if punch card or binary. Printing is done by interpreting the punch code (also a function of the 029). Assignment of a 5x7 glyph to a code was done using a mechanical code plate. This code plate was exchangeable at customer request . 1/+

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd European customers were using country specific plates - same way as they were using country (and customer) specific type blocks on chain printers. While I only started in mainframe service in 1977, I still had to live and handle all those quirks in hardware (including 029 maintenance) - and not much later later as programmer. 2/-

Comment: @UncleBod Western Europeans complaining about the **AMERICAN** Standard Code for Information Interchange always makes me laugh.  And is a bit presumptuous of them.

Comment: @RonJohn Those were ISO detivatives. Later discussion has primarily been about character sets in general.

Comment: The standard way is to have an optional byte order mark at the beginning of the file.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark.  Windows support this.   These days I would suggest just going with files on disk being in UTF-8 and then parse it into whatever internal representation you need.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, I know. But my original question- before somebody applied a well-intentioned edit- emphasised that I was interested in *legacy* files, and explained the era I was investigating. I also explicitly said "add something comparable with a Unicode BOM" i.e. distinct from the BOM itself.

Comment: For Algol 68 source, wouldn't **pragmat** *encoding* be the appropriate way?  After all, that's the way the stropping regime is indicated.

Comment: @another-dave It probably would, and in general I'm a great fan of pragmata.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd please re-edit your question thing instead of putting me (and the editor) down for not reading all the historical versions of your question.  You should have received a notification when the edit was made.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I've partially-reverted the edit, but I really can't see why somebody suddenly edited a subject line which had been sitting unmolested for around 10 months.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd That is how Stackoverflow works - encourage people to improve existing questions and answers.   It is still somewhat unclear to me what you consider a legacy file.

Comment: You talk about making sense for ASCII and EBCDIC, I presume that you know that they don't agree on the coding of A to Z, 0 to 9, or even space.

Comment: @badjohn Yes, but OTOH both- unlike some of their predecessors- had properties consistent with the assumptions Waite made when he wrote Stage2.

Comment: Sadly, "which code page is this file in" is still a very real problem in the world of EBCDIC.  It is possible to tag the file with  CCSID but it is common to not do do.

Comment: @badjohn TFT, is that explicitly an IBM mainframe thing and how is it stored (e.g. is it a short member inside a fileset or is it a property of a fileset or member)? Of course I suppose that we do have to consider EAs as used by OS/2 etc., although my initial intention related to the content of a file itself.

Comment: Also IBM minis such as the AS/400 and its successors (some of which are alive today).  I am familiar with these and not mainframes.  The tagging is in an attribute and not in the data.  I have never seen anything like a BOM in EBCDIC.

Comment: @badjohn I see CCSID also being used as an attribute by DB2 and possibly also by Oracle, which obviously has ramifications. My original question was because I was considering lexer coding to include things like legacy APL files, where being able to work out the encoding early has advantages (e.g. having the lexer convert input to Unicode).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The closest thing to a universal convention (in the sense that it can be applied to any kind of text file, not necessarily universal *adoption*) that I know of is Emacs’ [file-local variable declarations](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html):

```
-*- coding: cp437 -*-
```

This was first released in GNU Emacs in [Emacs 20.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.User.20.html), [released in 1997](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/history.html). It may have existed earlier in MULE.

The vim editor has a similar feature, called [modelines](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_21.html#21.6):

```
vim:set fileencoding=cp437
```

This was introduced in [Vim 5.2](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/version5.html#new-multi-byte), [released in 1998](https://github.com/vim/vim-history#release-history).

However, I can see some materials on the Web claiming that the latter does not work particularly well for encodings.  I don’t actually use either editor daily, so I cannot say anything about that.

Both served as inspiration for the Python encoding declaration standard, [PEP 263](https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/), adopted in 2001, which I guess is just barely old enough to count as ‘retrocomputing’ here.

Comment: As an aside, if the user ends up doing this as a pet project, this convention is reasonably widely supported in editors (or at least, PEP263 is). The difficult part of languages is always documentation and tooling.

Answer (score 15):

When 8-bit codepages were in use, files were rarely transferred from one computer to another that used a different character set. So all files on the filesystem were assumed to contain text in the system's codepage.

The MIME system used for email (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#History) was one of the first systems that had in band signalling of what charset was in use.

Comment: My experience selling and maintaining software from the late 70s onwards is that it /does/ matter, since apart from anything else when software is shipped it typically (unless written by linguistic chauvinists) includes tailored documentation etc.

Comment: "Rarely?" _A lot_ of files was transferred from one computer to another just in the Win9x era that I remember – floppy disks to carry documents between home computer and workplace, SMB shares at work. And even here, as late to the Internet as we were, web and email was definitely a thing in 1998. (Websites had content-type tags, but MS Word documents were already being sent around that didn't have anything of that sort.)

Comment: MS-DOS systems here went through _five_ different national "system codepages" for the same language (with TSRs to switch between 770, 771, 773 on the fly), then Windows added two more – older computers running Win3.11 had a [switcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXrMl.png) to select between two "system codepages" as 1257 was still new; newer ones running Win98 had a MS Office addon for converting .doc's between the two as well as from DOS codepages to Windows ones. (Not to mention documents that needed Russian codepages, or even half-773/half-866 in the same file...)

Comment: @user1686 Plus there was also the widely-popular Kermit which was regularly used to move data around within an institution, and of course BBSes and Compuserve etc. And a particular issue- predating PCs- was the couple of characters which were redefined relatively late in ASCII: ^ and _ vs up- and left-arrow (used e.g. in Smalltalk) if my memory is correct.

Comment: @grawity: That's a full 30 years after the late 60s ALGOL/PASCAL stuff being talked about here.  PCs did not exist yet at that time.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Paul says "When 8-bit codepages were in use" and does not mention ALGOL/PASCAL as part of that. The claim that files were rarely transferred from computer to computer _when 8-bit codepages were in use_ is false and it's what I am responding to. (And for that matter, the existence of Pascal very much overlaps with the existence of PCs... we were taught Pascal in school in the year ~2000 on Windows PCs using FreePascal. It was a pre-UTF8 version that used 8-bit codepages, and its files were indeed moved between computers.)

Comment: Yes they were transfered to other computers, but almost always to another computer that used the same character set. MS-DOS did not have any means to convert between character sets as far as I'm aware. It seems to me there would have been if there were many people asking for one.

Comment: Plus, many 8 bit character sets are ASCII based which means the first 127 characters were the same (numbers, basic punctuation and unaccented roman letters in both upper case and lower case). So even if the set in use wasn't the same as the one a text file came from it could still be mostly readable.

Comment: I patched up a version of Kermit to work in MP/M-86 and then used it to transfer between an Altos 586 and an IBM mainframe. So ASCII to EBCDIC. Except, *not quite*, because the terminal interface I used was an emulation running on an IBM Series/1 which let ASCII terminals (Wyse, ADM, Televideo, Hazeltine, etc.) run in a 3270-emulation mode. But the end result of all that did indeed include a character set conversion. File transfer was in now way limited to "similar computers" (IBM PC to IBM PC or Apple to Apple or whatever).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact Sure, it could be done in the period being asked about. But there was no standardized in-band mechanism to identify what was being used. My point here is that it was done infrequently enough that developers of software included with systems of the time didn't see encoding conversion as enough of an issue that they needed to account for it somehow. If you did character encoding conversions you were kind of on your own.

Answer (score 5):

Browsers and other programs that attempted to automatically deduce the character encoding of text files would scan them for patterns, such as opening and closing quotation marks, or common words in the language.  This sometimes went hilariously wrong, with the most famous example being the version of Windows that misread the line “Bush hid the facts” as UTF-16 and turned it into mojibake. (You had to be there.)

The closest thing to this in wide use is the HTML element

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=..." />
```

This originally told the browser to start over and, this time, parse the document as if the server had sent that MIME type in the HTTP header, and was therefore usually put as close to the top as it could be.  It was later simplified to `<meta charset=... />` in HTML 5. However, if you tell a browser that your document is in the Latin-1 encoding, it (as the standard mandates) will actually assume it is in Windows code page 1252.

I’m still in the habit of saving my C and C++ source files with a byte-order mark, since without one, Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 would interpret them as the currently-active code page, and that version provided no other way to override this.  The current version of MSVC does attempt to auto-detect the encoding, but why take chances? GCC assumes UTF-8 but provides command-line options to override this, and Clang, last I checked, only reads UTF-8, so UTF-8 with a byte-order mark works on all modern compilers with no flags needed, and is the only encoding all of them understand.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142751/discussion-on-answer-by-davislor-codepages-in-legacy-textfiles); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The general way this has been done for pretty much forever, is to have a set of 'patterns' (perhaps rexexps, perhaps something else) that are run against the file and the first (or highest priority) one that matches sets the encoding to use for the file.

This may be a fixed set encoded directly in each application that wants to access files, or there might be a standard database on the system that all applications use -- it depends on the OS.  There might be a `magic` or `.mime.types` file somewhere that has this database and may be extendible by users to deal with any weird file they might come across, or might be in some proprietary form that is not (easily) extended.

Comment: That's the general way for file *formats* (as in structure), but I don't think I've ever seen `magic` being used to distinguish text encodings in structureless text files. Do you know of a specific way to tag different encodings that's commonly used (which was OP's question) or are you saying it's possible to detect different encodings using just regex?

Comment: @grawity OP here. I think the closest possible thing is the use of modelines (etc.) in the accepted answer, even though when I posed the question I was hoping for something (e.g.) embedded in the EOF marker. The problem with any form of magic is that the characters that distinguish various CPs are likely to be relatively rare, /except/ when distinguishing between e.g. Western and Middle/Far-Eastern character sets. The specific case I was originally wondering about was pre-Unicode representation of APL, for which at least two ASCII-based fonts exist plus at least one EBCDIC.